# SATA2 disk detected as SATA

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, sata

I have 2 Hitachi Deskstar HDS728080PLA380 Drives, with SATA2 (3.0Gbs interface), that are only detected as SATA1 (1.5Gbs) by both Intel Rapid Storage Manager and other similar software in Windows 8. My Motherboard is a Gigabyte Z77X-UD3H, and all ports support SATA2 drives. Is it a BIOS or a hdd firmware problem, or am I missing something?

Comment: Could be the cable but probably not that big of a deal as that won't saturate SATA1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, do not worry, SATA1 SATA2 or SATA3 won't really impact your HDD performance unless you operate huge volumes of information 24-7. Think about SATA as a doorway: If you alone and you run, it does not matter how large the doorway is--as long as you run fast, you are OK. Just make sure that it reads and writes up to specifications.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check:

1. drive jumoers - (some drives come with jumoers for compatibility)
2. bios settings - (possible there are BIOS settings that cab affect this)
3. cable - (you need a SATA 2 compliant cable)